# How can I yank multiple lines into a register?

Tags: vim, editing

I want to yank multiple lines in a single register in vim, to easily paste different text templates in a document.

For example, "iyy yanks only the the current line, if I try to select multiple lines in visual-mode, it isn't written into the register.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "if i try to select multiple lines in visual-mode, it isn't written into the register." <-- Really? Works for me...

Comment: and for me too...

Comment: ah ok, i've tried with "iyv, silly me. should be Vjjj"iy like ulidtko mentioned.

Comment: Similar: [How to store all occurrences of a multiline search in a register?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/11791/467)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Use `3Y` to yank 3 lines into the default register; `"i3Y` for yanking into register i.

Also, my favorite way is not to count the lines I want to yank, but to select them in visual mode via `V` and moving commands, and then hit `y` to yank it or `"_y` to yank into a register.

Also, I have just tried selecting multiple lines in Visual Line mode and yanking into not-default register, e.g. `Vjjj"oy` — and it works.

Comment: +1 - but `V` is Visual Line Mode, `v` is visual mode.

Comment: ok, ok, right. Visual Line Mode. `%)`

Comment: gladly accepted it, fastest way for me yet.

Answer (score 32):

From anywhere within the file, you can use the following.

```
:2,5y a
```

Yank lines 2 - 5. ***INTO REGISTER a***

```
:7pu a
```

Paste register a under line 7.

Comment: The question asked, “how can I yank multiple lines ***into a register***?”  Please show how these commands work with registers.

Comment: I hope my edit fulfills your request.

Comment: Sorry, no.  The question explicitly mentioned "register" repeatedly, referred to "easily paste different text templates", and gave an example using a non-default register.

Comment: My apologies. Your first comment was unclear as to what a valid and correct answer should contain. I falsely presumed that the asker would understand, like myself, that many vim commands work in multiple modes. Since the asker showed his aptitude in yanking into both default and named registers, I foolishly omitted that component of my answer. I would also note that this works best with `:set number` so one may see the line numbers of the range to yank. Now, if you'll please remove your down vote as my answer is clearly the best.

Comment: For your information, when you respond to a comment (in a new comment), it’s conventional to mention the author’s name, preceded by “@”, as in “@Scott” (don’t include spaces in the name).  That way he gets notified.  See the **Replying in comments** paragraphs of [the **Comment formatting** section](http://superuser.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) of the Markdown Editing Help page.  I haven’t been doing that here because the author of a post is automatically notified of comments to that post (as, I presume, you have experienced).

Comment: You say, “I falsely presumed that the asker would understand, like myself, that many `vim` commands work in multiple modes.  Since the asker showed his aptitude in yanking into both default and named registers, I foolishly omitted that component of my answer.”  First of all, it may be more accurate to say that `vim` has multiple modes, and _different commands_ are available in the different modes.  (continued...)

Comment: (continued)  Secondly, I believe that your statement makes about as much sense as “I recommend Alice’s restaurant.  I presume you know how to drive; therefore, I ***won’t*** give you directions how to get there.”  The point is that different modes are … what’s the word I’m looking for here? … oh yes: different modes are ***different***.  The best example is the “mark” command, which is `m` in visual mode and `k` in command mode.  That’s why I asked you to show how the `:y` and `:pu` commands work with registers.  (continued...)

Comment: (continued)  Thirdly, you’re not sending an email to “ryz” (the person who asked the question).  You’re posting an answer that may very well sit here for years and be found by Google searches by people who don’t know `vim` as well as “ryz” does, so you should provide useful information.  But I’m leaving out the biggest thing: ***YOUR ANSWER IS WRONG!***  The right answer is `:y a` and `:pu a`.  Finally, you say, “my answer is clearly the best.”  Why in the world do you believe that?  Even after you correct the error with the **`"`** characters, your answer will be only _as good_ as the others.

Comment: @Scott My apologies. Why didn't you just say, "Dude, check your method with :reg. You'll see it doesn't work." And I would've been all like, "Whoa, my bad".

Comment: Was looking for a way to yank the who file into register + for copying to system clipboard.  :%y + did the trick, thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Use `m` to mark the start, with a buffer name (so you might type `mx`). Move your cursor down to where you want to stop copying, and type `y'x` (or `d'x` if you're cutting and pasting). Then move the to the point where you want to paste, and type `p`.

[The Vim command cheat sheet](https://www.fprintf.net/vimCheatSheet.html)

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `v` not `m`?

Comment: @BillyONeal  'v' starts Visual Mode, and allows you to do the same thing, 'm' is used for "marking" a region.

Answer (score 7):

You prefix the command with a number to get how many lines to operate on.  You could also use a 'text-object' (like ']' for block, and ')' for paragraph) - this would work on multiple lines contextually - the default is often a single line.  For example, `"r5yy` would yank five lines starting at the cursor into the 'r' register.  (Or you could type `:.,+4y r` to do the same in ex mode.) You can combine numbers with text-objects as well; `"r10y)`.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to yank multiple lines in case when it is a last search occurrence.

For example given the following [a multiline non-greedy pattern](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_across_multiple_lines#Searching_for_multiline_HTML_comments):

```
/start\_.\{-}end/norm gn"iy
```

then you'll have your yanked multiline pattern (between `start` and `end`) in your `@i` register (print by `echo @i`).

Related: [How to print a multi-line match?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/5144/467) at Vi

Answer (score 0):

Somehow we’ve missed that `y`ank is an *operator*, which means it works on all *motions* and *text-objects* (see the relevant help sections).

That means that `yip`, `y)`, `ygg`, `yib`, etc., all work (and with registers, too)! They can potentially be multiple lines.

Note that some motions are not line-wise by default. You can use `yV{motion}` to force a line-wise yank.

Answer (score 0):

Might be not much related to this question. However, if someone needs to copy all lines into a register do it with `%`

```
:%y a
```